# Accelerator, load dataset from string in buildscript

Tags: python

I have a chained dataset stored in a  workdir that i want to access from a build script.
I know I can pass the dataset as a string to a job, but i really want to work on the chain 
directly in the build script.

```py
def main(urd):
    chained_ds_name = 'dev-40/my-chained'
    chained_ds = ?? (chained_ds_name) <-- what goes here ?

    for ds in chained_ds.chain():
        urd.build("some_job", ds=ds)
```

I am not sure what to do with `??`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from accelerator.dataset import Dataset
chained_ds = Dataset(chained_ds_name)
```

Normally you would be expected to get 'dev-40' from urd in which case it will already be a Job object, so you would do something like

```
urd.latest('something').joblist['my_method'].dataset('my-chained')
```